# Subtag context in DotLiquid (with forms)

Tags: c#, .net-core, liquid, dotliquid

I'd like to be able to access the object passed to a form tag in DotLiquid within child tags. Something like this:

```
{% form '/action' requestObject %}
    {% textinput Name %}
    <button type="submit">Create Request</button>
{% endform %}
```

Where the `textinput` tag looks for a `name` field on `requestObject` and then puts the value into a text input field. My liquidese is a rather rusty so if I'm going about this all wrong I'm open to coherent screaming about what a dolt I am and what I need to do to be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily done in the tag renderer with `Context`'s `Stack`:

```
public class Form : Block
{
    // public override void Initialize...
    public override void Render(Context context, TextWriter writer)
    {
        context.Stack(() =>
        {
            context["form_obj"] = new FormObject();
            result.Write("<form>");
            base.Render(context, result);
            result.Write("</form>");
        }
    }
}
```

Before running the action passed to it, `Stack` pushes a new Hash variable stack (that looks up the chain for unset variables) and then pops it at the end. Perfect for localized scope of variables.